# c# - Application structure & passing read serial data back to my main form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, class, serial-port

I would like some advice on the structure of my windows form application. My application will allow the user to open a `SerialPort` in order to read data from a USB device.
Currently, the application will open into the main form, the user would then open another form `frmPortConfig` in order to configure the port, this form would then be closed and the user would return to the main form. As it stands, the user selects the port, clicks open, the port info is then passed to another port config class and is setup.

How would I then pass this data back to the main form? 
Is this the correct/most efficient method of achieving this?

**port config form:**

```
public partial class frmPortConfig : Form
{
    public frmPortConfig()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //center the form
        this.CenterToScreen();
        //get serial ports
        getPorts();
    }

    public void getPorts()
    {
        //stop user from editing the combo box text
        cmbPortList.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        //get the available ports
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        //add the array of ports to the combo box within the 
        cmbPortList.Items.AddRange(ports);
    }


    private void btnOpenPort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get name of port
        string port = cmbPortList.SelectedItem.ToString();

        //if the port string is not null
        if (port != null)
        {
            //if port can be opened (evoke open port code in port class)
            if (clsPortConfig.openPort(port))
            {
                //inform user that port has been opened
                lblPortStatus.Text = port + " opened successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                //inform user that port could not be opened
                lblPortStatus.Text = port + " could not be opened";
            }
        }          
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //close the form
        this.Close();
    }
```

**port config class:**

```
class clsPortConfig
{

    public static bool openPort(string port)
    {
        try
        {
            //create new serial port
            SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();

            //serial port settings
            serialPort.PortName = port;
            serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

            //attempt to open serial port
            serialPort.Open();
            serialPort.ReadTimeout = 200;

            //add data received handle to serial port
            serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_DataReceived);

            //if serial port is now open
            if (serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                //inform user that the port could not be opened
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //set sender up as serial port
        SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort)sender;

        //get data from serial port
        string data = serialPort.ReadExisting();            
    }
}
```

How should I send the received data back to my main form?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how would I then pass this data back to the main form?

Since you catch the data asynchronously from the device via an event. You don't know when it will arrive. So you would need an event which you can fire from the `clsPortConfig`.

```
class clsPortConfig
{

    public delegate void EventHandler(string s);
    public static event EventHandler TransmitEvent;

    // all the other stuff

    public static void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //set sender up as serial port
        SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort)sender;

        //get data from serial port
        string data = serialPort.ReadExisting();

        if (TransmitEvent != null)
        {
            TransmitEvent(data);
        }
    }

}
```

and register it in the form:

```
public frmPortConfig()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //center the form
    this.CenterToScreen();
    //get serial ports
    getPorts();

    clsPortConfig.TransmitEvent += MyTransmitEvent;
}

private void MyTransmitEvent(string s)
{
    // in s you will find the data
}
```

> Is this the correct/most efficient method of achieving this?

I would doubt that. There are a lot of ways to do that. You chose a rather convoluted one. The easiest would probably be to have everything in the `Form` class. Have the `SerialPort` there, register the `DataReceived` event also and use the [BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx) method to access display controls like `TextBox` if you want to show the received data. Because it will arrive on a different thread then the control is created in.

Comment: Thank you for your concise answer! I knew there would be a simple way of passing the data around my forms. So do you think I would actually be better off doing this all within my main form? I thought it would make my code cleaner by having it done in separate classes etc.

Comment: It depends. If it is only a small application for communicating a few commands and receive some output which you only display, then it would suffice to handle everything in the form. If on the other hand you would like to distribute it on different pc's and the probability is high that application will change soon and often it might be advisable to separate the GUI from the logic. But then you would need to put the Class that handles the communication and everything else into a separate DLL-project. So that you can just exchange the DLL file and not recompile at each update.